# Prevent Amazon Mobile app expiration

Tags: iphone, ios-appstore, ipod-touch

I'm running my old Amazon app on iPod Touch 2G. On opening the app I noticed something peculiar happened: it said "Please update your app, the app you using, will be retired on June 30, (pushed back from July 1st)" I got that many moons ago (late April/early May).

How do I prevent this from happening? I want to track my orders.

Comment: If you're already on iOS 4.2.1 & you cannot update the app any further, I'd say you're stuck, unfortunately.

Comment: is there an Alternative or equivalent to Amazon mobile app?

Comment: There is not. It has to come from Amazon since they provide you access to your account and the information with in.

Answer (score 4):

You can't. The API that the app uses is to be turned off and will no longer be able to be used to provide information to the app, thus making the app non-functional.

Comment: Amazon.com works well on mobile devices. Unfortunately it sounds like you will have to use that instead.